# How do I group column1 and column2 add the sum of each pair regardless of order according to year?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have a .csv file in this format.

| column1 | column2 | Count | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5 | 1990 |
| A | B | 2 | 2000 |
| A | C | 5 | 2000 |
| B | A | 10 | 1990 |

Using Python/excel, how do I  group column1 and column2 such that the order does not matter and add the total count of each pair according to year? E.g. results should be:

| column1 | column2 | Count | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 15 | 1990 |
| A | B | 2 | 2000 |
| A | C | 5 | 2000 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "col1": ["A", "A", "A", "B"],
    "col2": ["B", "B", "C", "A"],
    "Count": [5, 2, 5, 10],
    "Year": [1990, 2000, 2000, 1990],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
cols = ["col1", "col2"]
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols]))
df = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "Year"])["Count"].sum().reset_index()
df = df[["col1", "col2", "Count", "Year"]]
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
  col1 col2  Count  Year
0    A    B     15  1990
1    A    B      2  2000
2    A    C      5  2000
```

Comment: op wants to add. not max

Comment: @diggusbickus Just saw he made an edit. Anyway updated the answer.

Comment: oh you're right i didn't see he edited, sorry